# Как создать сайт, который собирает заголовки с постов с других сайтов, и дает ссылки на этот пост

Tags: веб-программирование

Например, существует пять сайтов которые постят ежедневно по 10 статей. Надо сделать сайт, который выкладывает у себя заголовок поста с ссылкой на оригинал. Прям чтоб выложили и через несколько секунд выкладывалось у в этом сайте.

Comment: Я делал такую штуку. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую так и не смог решить - на разных сайтах часто выкладывают одну и ту же статью, но отрерайченную. Вычислить такие "дубли" оказалось задачей очень и очень нетривиальной, в рамках такого простенького сервиса

Comment: @AidarAibekov вопрос слишком широк, какой ответ вы ожидаете услышать?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan В принципе пойдет простенький сайт, может быть написан на вордпресс. Может кто-то может поделиться своим опытом или полезными ссылками для решения задачи. Сайт в своем роде сборник источников которые постят что-то, а этот сайт перепостит это но не копируя весь текст, а взяв лишь заголовок и ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужен обычный Parser html страничек.

Т.е пишется скрипт, который проходит по странице обрабатывая определенные html теги.

Полученные данные, записываешь в БД.

А уже потом выводишь эти данные на свой сайт.

И скрипт нужно засунуть в "cron", чтобы допустим каждые 5 минут приходился по всем сайтам.

Comment: какие библиотеки посоветуете использовать? Библиотеки на PHP или другие можно например?

Comment: @AidarAibekov,  честно, с такой задачей не сталкивался, так что библиотеки не смогу посоветовать. Вот [ссылка](https://tproger.ru/digest/parse-html-via-php/) небольшой список библиотек, которые можно использовать.